# Inequality for a non-decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,+\infty] \rightarrow R^+$ be non-decreasing with $$\int_{2r}^{4r} f(t) dt \leq C \int_{r}^{2r} f(t) dt \qquad \forall r \geq 0$$

To prove $f(2r)\leq C' f(r) \qquad \forall r\geq 0$

$\\$

Don't know from where to start. Maybe to use Lebesgue differentiation theorem and write $$f(2r)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_{2r-\epsilon}^{2r+\epsilon} f(t) dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $f$ is non-decreasing. In particular $f(2r)\le f(t)$ for $t\in(2r,4r)$ and $f(t)\le f(r)$ for $t\in(r/2,r)$, so $$2r\,f(2r)=\int_{2r}^{4r}f(2r)\le\int_{2r}^{4r}f(t)
\le C\int_r^{2r}f(t)\le C^2\int_{r/2}^rf(t)\le C^2\int_{r/2}^rf(r)=\frac{C^2r}{2}f(r).$$Divide by $2r$.